# Removing a field from a form within a patch and deploying to target environment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I recently created a new patch where I removed a field from the main form of one of my custom entities. I didn't delete it from the entity because I want to retain any old data on the target environment, just removed it from the form.

The patch was deployed onto another environment where the same field still existed on the form on the base solution.

I expected the patch to update the same form on the target environment but it didn't, its still on the other form. I have no idea where to go from here, what do I need to do in order to remove a field from a form on the target environment?

Comment: I'm not a managed solution expert, but any chance that the field has been deployed as part of an unmanaged solution?

Comment: @Daryl Hi there, no it was definitely deployed as a managed solution (patch). When I open the patch on the target environment Im not able to edit it as a managed solution

Comment: Yeah, you can't edit managed solutions...

Comment: Can you check (using the Solution Layer feature) if there's any unamanaged changes on the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across something similar before - hopefully you're facing the same issue -

The form in question may have an Active unmanaged layer in your target environment that is effectively superseding your installed managed solution. You can check this within a solution by switching to classic > navigating to the form > select the form > select 'Solution Layers' under 'more actions'.

If there is an unmanaged layer, you will see it at the top (listed as the Active item).
[image: Solution Layers with an unmanaged top layer]

You can delete this unmanaged layer by clicking the elipses (3 dots) and selecting 'Remove Active Customisations'.

If this is a test or prod environment, those customisations probably should not be there anyways. It's easy for this mistake to occur if you open the form editor and save and close without making any changes - this effectively creates the unmanaged layer

Answer (score 1):

If no unmanaged layer found, then one possibility is because you are using an out of the box form.
You added an attribute on the form. When exporting, the solution contains the difference between the managed form and the unmanaged layer you created. Your attribute is added in the target form.
Then you remove the attribute from the form. When you export the patch, there is no difference between the out of of the box form and the version of the form you have (platform cannot say « this attribute has been removed » because there is no difference). So when importing the patch, it cannot find that an attribute has been removed, so it is not removed in the target env.

Solution: do not use out of the box form for standard entities but create your own forms.
Or just set the attribute visibility to false instead of removing je field